# How to get the calculation steps for factorials?

Tags: swift, math

I know how to get the factorial answer with recursion

```
func factorial(n: Int) -> Int {
    if n == 0 { return 1 }
    else { return n * factorial(n - 1)
}
```

If I passed factorial(5) the method would return 120, but is it possible to get the calculation? 
What I mean is if I had a function called breakDownFactorial and if i called breakDownFactorial(5) it would return 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1, if i called breakDownFactorial(4) it would return 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
and so on.

Comment: Do you need to only display the factorial calculation ? If so, why not use a linear traversal to do that ? The OP question and its content are somewhat misleading. If you want to speed up the actual calculation of factorial, you can use dynamic programming technique.

Comment: By the way, the function, you are using gives an exponential time complexity, you are much better off using dynamic programming, if you want to use this function in actual application.

Comment: How would I write this with dynamic programming?

Comment: This link might be helpful https://gyaneshwarpardhi.wordpress.com/2014/05/17/factorial-program-using-dynamic-programming/

Comment: A good tutorial on DP by topcoder : https://www.topcoder.com/community/data-science/data-science-tutorials/dynamic-programming-from-novice-to-advanced/

Comment: @CyprUS How is does the recursive factorial have exponential runtime? The first link you’ve given doesn’t use dynamic programming techniques, but *memoization* to speed up repeated calls.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not *entirely* sure what you mean by "get the calculation", but to get a string representation of the calculation, you can do something like this:

```
func breakDownFactorial(n: Int) -> String {
  return (1...n).reverse().map(String.init).joinWithSeparator(" * ")
}

breakDownFactorial(5) // 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

Answer (score 2):

With small modifications, `factorial` can be converted to `breakDownFactorial` which returns the string description of the factorial calculation:

```
func breakDownFactorial(n: Int) -> String {
    if n == 0 { return "1" }
    else {
        return "\(n) * " + breakDownFactorial(n - 1)
    }
}

breakDownFactorial(10) // "10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1"
```

---

The extra `"* 1"` accurately reflects how the original `factorial` function works.  If you wish to eliminate it, change the recursive base case to:

```
if n <= 1 { return "1" }
```

Comment: Almost, but the duplicant `* 1` differs from what the OP was asking for.